# How can I configure tomcat to log on a different file using log4j?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I'm trying to log certain messages on a different file on my tomcat installation, using log4j, but although it does log on my rootLogger it doesn't do it on the separate file I am creating.

Here is my log4j.properies file, where the file I'm trying to use is dataflow_logging.log:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, mainlogger

# Direct dataflow specific messages to specific file.
log4j.logger.org.estat.nsiws.dataflows=INFO, dataflowlogger
log4j.appender.dataflowlogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dataflowlogger.File=${catalina.home}/logs/nsi/dataflow_logging.log
log4j.appender.dataflowlogger.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.dataflowlogger.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.dataflowlogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dataflowlogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Disable dataflow log messages in root logger.
log4j.additivity.org.estat.nsiws.dataflows=false

# Direct main logging messages to standard output.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%p]: %m%n

# Also direct main logging messages to file.
log4j.appender.mainlogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.mainlogger.File=${catalina.home}/logs/nsi/nsiws.log
log4j.appender.mainlogger.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.mainlogger.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.mainlogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mainlogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%p]: %m%n
```

My WebService's properties file:

```
## This file contains properties for the Web Service

# The absolute path to the logs directory
log.directory=logs/nsi

# The log file prefix
log.file.prefix=nsiws_

# The log file suffix
log.file.suffix=.log

# The prefix of the temporary files created for the buffering of responses.
tempfile.buffer.prefix=ws_resp

# Enable logging dataflow access
log.df.file.activation=true

# The absolute path to the dataflow logs directory
log.df.file.directory=logs/nsi

# The dataflow log file prefix
log.df.file.name=dataflow_logging

# The dataflow log file maximum size
log.df.file.max.size=100MB

# The dataflow max backup file
log.df.file.max.backup=10

# The dataflow log file separator
log.df.file.separator=;

# The dataflow log file date pattern
log.df.date.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS};%m%n
```

The method that initialises the dataflow logger:

```
private static Logger initDataflowLogger() {
        Logger dflogger = null;

        try {
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(nsiProps.getProperty("log.df.file.activation"))) {
                dflogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.estat.nsiws.dataflows");
                dflogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
                logger.debug("Initializing dataflow logging...");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(getInstance().getMessage("error.df.log.properties.not.set"));
        }

        return dflogger;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this expression is true and if you have set your properties file correctly, so your project can read from it.

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(nsiProps.getProperty("log.df.file.activation"))
```

Comment: You were right. I had not set the file correctly, so the expression was always false...

Answer (score 0):

1. Your root logger is in INFO mode.
2. Which will not log the debug level statement.
3. You have taken the instance of org.estat.nsiws.dataflows (dataflowlogger Appender), which is "dflogger" but you are actually calling "logger.debug"